# Can't tap on UILabel during animated

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have set animation with UILabel. And I add UITapGestureRecognizer for UILabel. But, I can not tap on UILabel.

**This is my code:**

*Add gesture for UILabel:*

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnLabel:)];
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    _lbAnimation.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [_lbAnimation addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

*Animation UILabel*

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
             _lbAnimation.frame=CGRectMake(0-(rect.size.width), _lbAnimation.frame.origin.y, rect.size.width, _lbAnimation.frame.size.height);

         } completion:^(BOOL finished)
          {
              _viewAnimation.hidden = YES;
          }];
```

**handleTapOnLabel function**

```
- (void)handleTapOnLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInLabel = [tapGesture locationInView:tapGesture.view];
    NSLog(@"_lbAnimation: %f : %f", locationOfTouchInLabel.x, locationOfTouchInLabel.y);
}
```

I don't know cause UILabel not tap.

Please help me.

Comment: @Thauan Nguyen where have you implemented your target action -: handleTapOnLabel?

Comment: I have update. Please check again help me.